# Natural sorting when characters and numbers mixed

Tags: postgresql, sorting

I have a table column which is straightforwards alphanumerical but also can have variations from the norm.

```
AB1
AB2
AB2a
AB3
AB4
AB11
AB11a
```

Is how I want to sort it

I tried ORDER BY split_part but it failed because some have an 'a' on the end.

Comment: You _"tried ORDER BY split_part"_ - what is `split_part`? What exactly did you try?

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/split_part-function.php

Comment: I can see why you'd have trouble with that. You have no delimiters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to normalise the format of the numeric portion of the text. You can do that by splitting the string into the `AB` prefix and the numeric part, then left-padding the numeric part to a consistent length with zeroes.

For example: AB11a becomes AB00011a.

Apply this to all the items you've listed and they'll sort in the order you want.

You can do this with

```
    ... ORDER BY concat(substring(`code`,1,2),lpad(substr(`code`,3),6,'0')) ...

where `code` is the name of the column that contains the data you want to sort.
```

Note - this assumes that the prefix is always 2 characters.

Comment: This works well, but puts all items which end in 'A' at the bottom of the list, so AB11A doesn't come between AB11 and AB12